# flink - unable to start job cluster

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to start flink job cluster.
I've cofigured HA to zookeeper and placed job.jar to classpath.
I'm expecting the jobmanager starts with one job waiting to taskmanagers starts.
But when I starts jobmanager via `./flink/bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground` jobmanager starts executing the job immediately without any taskmanager running. And WebUI says: 
`{
errors: [
"Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh."
]
}`

The job is written in Apache Beam and the behavior is similar to start the job manually with `java -jar job.jar --runner=DirectRunner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in missing argument. Flink just run the main method and beam uses DirrectRunner as default. So the job does not run on flink. This command works: `./flink/bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --runner=org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner`